# Indenting Xml file edited with XDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have some code that edits and Xml file.
When I save the file the new elements are not properly indented while existing elements are, e.g.:

Before:

```xml
  <MyGroup>  
    <ExistingElement1>a value</ExistingElement1>
    <ExistingElement2>something else</ExistingElement2>
  </MyGroup>
```

After:

```xml
  <MyGroup>  
    <ExistingElement1>a value</ExistingElement1>
    <ExistingElement2>something else</ExistingElement2>
  <NewElement>Inserted by code</NewElement></MyGroup>
```

New elements are added with XElement, like:

```cs
myGroup.Add(new XElement(ns + "NewElement", "Inserted by code"));
```

when saving the file I use XmlWriterSettings as I want to avoid saving the XmlDeclaration:

```cs
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
  OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
  Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
  Indent = true
};
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{
  xmlDoc.Save(writer);
}
```

So it looks like that the `Indent = true` option is not working for the newly added elements, does anyone know why?

BTW, when I open the file I use `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`

```cs
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

Comment: There's no difference between old and new elements as soon as they all get there. It would appear that it does indent, but not with the amount of whitespace that you expect. Let it discard the whitespace between the old nodes to see what happens.

Comment: Haven't tested yet but likely `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` + `<NewElement>` cause `<MyGroup>` to be identified as having [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content) -- i.e. both child elements and text content.  And from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent?view=net-5.0#remarks): *The elements are indented as long as the element does not contain mixed content. Once the WriteString or WriteWhitespace method is called to write out a mixed element content, the XmlWriter stops indenting.*

Comment: You are missing : settings.Indent = true;

Comment: @jdweng - it's right there: `var settings = new XmlWriterSettings{ /* ... */ Indent = true }`

Comment: Why are you using `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`?  You're basically loading all the indentation in the input XML into `XText` nodes in your `XDocument`.  Not only does that disable `XmlWriterSettings.Indent` but also it takes up more memory.

Comment: @dbc, removing LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace does fix the indentation problem, thanks! However I wanted to retain the whitespace as I am editing hundreds of Xml files which have user friendly formatting applied to them which I wished to keep.
In fact there is other formatting I wanted to preserve such as elements with long list of attributes that I wanted to keep as new lines but that are all reformatted into single lines.

Comment: @Techromancer - then you are going to need to manually insert `XText` nodes corresponding to the indenting you want for `<NewElement>`.  See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/preserve-white-space-loading-parsing-xml and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/preserve-white-space-serializing